# How to overcome OutOfMemory error from my android app.?

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory, android-bitmap

I am creating an app which loaded six bitmaps as button background to change button states when user performs some actions on that but some times it gives error like

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

And I am using following method in MainActivity to set bitmap:

```
            on_duty.setBackgroundDrawable(GetApplicationDrawable
                    .Button3(R.drawable.on_duty_d));
            off_duty.setBackgroundDrawable(GetApplicationDrawable
                    .Button3(R.drawable.off_duty));
            journey_start.setBackgroundDrawable(GetApplicationDrawable
                    .Button3(R.drawable.journey));
            journey_end.setBackgroundDrawable(GetApplicationDrawable
                    .Button3(R.drawable.destination_d));
            metting_in.setBackgroundDrawable(GetApplicationDrawable
                    .Button3(R.drawable.meeting));
            metting_out.setBackgroundDrawable(GetApplicationDrawable
                    .Button3(R.drawable.over_d));
```

And my Button3 method inside my GetApplicationDrawable class like bellow to decode bitmaps

```
public static Drawable Button3(int res_id) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                res_id);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
    float newWidth = (float) ((float) wt / 3);
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float newHeight = (float) ((float) wt / 4);
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    Bitmap mannagedBitmap = bitmapMannagement(context.getResources(),
            res_id, width, height);
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mannagedBitmap,
            (int) newWidth, (int) newHeight, true);
    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), resizedBitmap);
    return d;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Eeek, why is that static? And upper-case? I recommend you use smaller bitmaps -- how large are they? -- and clean up code that's unnecessarily static.

Comment: I have removed static and problem remains same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this code fails you need to get out of the function or handle it gracefully.

```
try {
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            res_id);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // here you need to get out of the function 
    // or recover gracefully
    //TODO set the bitmap to a default bitmap.
    //TODO or return a null;
}
```